# How to convert Redline from Navisworks XML to Forge

Tags: xml, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-navisworks

We are trying to create an addon for Google Sheets that will load Forge Viewer for NWD viewing. We’d like to load all information on viewpoints created on the original file, such as cut planes, hidden objects and Annotations. We found how to get the viewpoint camera data, the hidden objects but we’d like to know how to do the same with the ‘Redline’ data.

Does anybody have converted this data from the XML file to Markups on Forge Viewer?

Comment: The format of redline of Forge Viewer is a kind of svg. you can build the similar format with the data from Navisworks XML. and load the svg to Forge Viewer. This is a blog that might be helpful: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/stamp-markup-using-svg-file

Comment: Hello @XiaodongLiang, do you have any clue how to convert metadata from the XML file such as _rlellipse_, _rlline_, _rlcloud_ to the same notation of the **Forge viewer**. We noticed the tricky part you've done on the camera conversion from the XML to Forge, on this article [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/load-xml-navisworks-saved-viewpoints-forge-viewer-cameras). However, we don't have any clue how to do the same to Redline attribute. Can you help us?

Comment: you will need to read geometry attributes from xml of Navisworks, e,g. circle, get its center and radius. Next, follow the similar code to create svg element http://xahlee.info/js/js_scritping_svg_basics.html (note, it uses screen coordinate. so convert attributes of Navisworks xml (world coordinates to screen coordinates by viewer. worldToClient). Finally, add the svg to markup of Forge Viewer as the blog I mentioned in the first reply